# Viewpager and containers width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

in a fragment I have a ViewPager that instantiate views (viewpager is the top left white box, the view is the blue box with "AAAAA" inside, padded by 20dp):

[image]

The viewpager is "match_parent" inside his fragment. How to "shorten" the width of the containers of the viewpager to achieve a layout like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Done! setPageMargin with a negative value & padding inside the view! :)